# Tic-Tac-Toe Multiplayers with ASP.NET and SignalR. Create and send message to a group?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I've for example this link /Site/Tris/tris.aspx?sessionId=8a657a7b15ee44c39063c8ae45a6ed3b

This is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var proxy = $.connection.myHub;

        proxy.client.test = function () {
            $('input').hide();//for testing
        };

        // start connetion
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            var sessionId = $(document).getUrlParam("sessionId");
            proxy.server.joinGroup(sessionId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the hub:

```
 public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        this.Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
public void test(string x)
        {
            Clients.Group(x).test();
        }
```

This is the aspx code when I do a step:

```
 protected void Image_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "8a657a7b15ee44c39063c8ae45a6ed3b";

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.Group(s).test();
    }
```

When I call context.Clients.Group(s).test(); in js goes returns into the $.connection.hub.start and rejoin in the group adn test() is not called!
Why? How could I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that when I click on an image and there is an event in ASPX, it sends a POST request so the page is refreshed right after

```
 proxy.client.test = function () {
            $('input').hide();//for testing
        };`
```

is called.
I've to do all of this using only js avoid the POST request and the refresh.